# Is there solution how to set each animation's sprite position

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm creating a Megaman game.
I wonder how to set each animation's sprite position.

I want result like this;

[image]

but when I create animation, it results like this;

[image]

I think this happened because sprite's position is not set appropriately.
So I ask. How you solve this problem?

I mean, do you set sprite's position before creating animation with them?
or, is there any tools you use to solve these problems?

Thanks for reading. (Notify me when syntax error in my question. I'm not good at English)

I tried to upload this article couple of times. It's irritating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you used Unity's Sprite Editor to slice the sprite sheet. If yes, you can set the Pivot point to `Left` when slicing. This will solve the problem illustrated in your question.

In your case the pivot is probably set to `Center` which causes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should set each animation's sprite position in image editing or animation software, whichever you have used to create this spritesheet.